# Sklearn - How to predict probability for all target labels

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I have a data set with a target variable that can have 7 different labels. Each sample in my training set has only one label for the target variable.

For each sample, I want to calculate the probability for each of the target labels. So my prediction would consist of 7 probabilities for each row.

On the sklearn website I read about multi-label classification, but this doesn't seem to be what I want.

I tried the following code, but this only gives me one classification per sample.

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier())
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

Does anyone have some advice on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can do that by simply removing the `OneVsRestClassifer` and using [`predict_proba`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.predict_proba) method of the [`DecisionTreeClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html). You can do the following:

```
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

This will give you a probability for each of your 7 possible classes.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [scikit-multilearn](http://scikit.ml) - an extension of sklearn that handles multilabel classification. If your labels are not overly correlated you can train one classifier per label and get all predictions - try (after *pip install scikit-multilearn*):

```
from skmultilearn.problem_transform import BinaryRelevance    
classifier = BinaryRelevance(classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier())

# train
classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predict
predictions = classifier.predict(X_test)
```

Predictions will contain a sparse matrix of size (n_samples, n_labels) in your case - n_labels = 7, each column contains prediction per label for all samples.

In case your labels are correlated you might need more sophisticated methods for multi-label classification.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of scikit-multilearn, feel free to ask more questions.

Comment: In the recently released 0.0.4 version of scikit-multilearn you will find predict_proba implementations for problem transformation based multi-label classifiers methods. In the above case replace the last line with:

predictions = classifier.predict_proba(X_test)

Answer (score 3):

If you insist on using the `OneVsRestClassifer`, then you could also call `predict_proba(X_test)` as it is supported by `OneVsRestClassifer` as well.

For eg:

```
from sklearn.multiclass import OneVsRestClassifier
clf = OneVsRestClassifier(DecisionTreeClassifier())
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
pred = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

The order of the labels for which you get the result can be found in:

```
clf.classes_
```